# php isset , empty , null , = ""

Tags: forms, get, http-post, isset, is-empty

```
<div>
    <h2>How many services do you need ?</h2>
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="GET" name="fServ">
    <input type="number" name="numServ" />
    <input type="submit" value="SEND">
    </form>
<div>
    <?php

    if(isset($_GET['numServ'])){
        echo "We need ".$_GET['numServ']." services";
    }
    if(!isset($_GET['numServ'])){
        echo "We don't have any services yet.";
    }
    else if($_GET['numServ']=""){
        echo "Please put in a number";
    }
```

Say you have this following form, it works if I put in a number or access the form on first load. However I could never on the last if statement : ( Put in a number )

I have tried with POST and GET methods.
GET methods will show :   **.php?numServ=**

I tried :

```
if((isset($_POST['numServ']) && $_POST['numServ']=="")

if(empty($_POST['numServ']))

if(is_null($_POST['numServ']))

if($_POST['numServ'] == "")

if($_POST['numServ'] == null)
```

I stil can't fall in the last condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing I can see in code

```
if($_GET['numServ']="")
```

You are using assignment operator here 
Please replace it with

```
if($_GET['numServ']=="")
```

and you should be fine with get method

Comment: Opps ! Thanks ! Sometimes it helps to ask !

Comment: @hayonj yes .. np it happens often